# Magento Controller route is routing to controller's noRouteAction

Tags: magento

I'm building a Controller and when I call an Action I get a 404 Error (everything worked last week!). I'm calling the action using:

http://www.website.com/route/controllername/actionname

eg:

http://www.website.com/abcdef/test/echo

I have investigated the problem (using Mage::log('..')) and found out that the controller is being loaded. The controller's name is fine too. Further investigation revealed that the **noRouteAction** within my controller is being called.

ie my controller contains:

```
public function noRouteAction() {
  echo "noRoute Action";
}

public function echoAction() {
  echo "Echo Action";
}
```

When I call http://www.website.com/abcdef/test/echo I get "noRoute Action".

Why isn't echoAction being called?

---

**Edit:**

The config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abcdef_Web>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Abcdef_Web>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <abcdef>
                <class>Abcdef_Web_Helper</class>
            </abcdef>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
             <abcdef>
                <class>Abcdef_Web_Block</class>
             </abcdef>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <abcdef>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Abcdef_Web</module>
                    <frontName>abcdef</frontName>
                </args>
            </abcdef>
        </routers>   
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <abcdef>
                    <file>abcdef.xml</file>
                </abcdef>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>    

</config>
```

The controller class file: (TestController.php)

```
<?php

class Abcdef_Web_TestController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

  public function noRouteAction() {
    echo "noRoute Action";
  }

  public function echoAction() {
    echo "Echo Action";
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: please add your config.xml, full controller class file (with exact filenames!). It will really help to diagnose the problem

Comment: Hmm, I used your code (+ added appropriate `Abcdef_Web.xml` to app\etc\modules) and I see "Echo Action" on my screen. Try delete your `var\cache`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK found the problem!!!!

It seems that "Add Store Code to Urls" was set to yes, so Magento was expecting:

http://www.website.com/storecode/abcdef/test/echo

rather then:

http://www.website.com/abcdef/test/echo

For those with the same problem. This can be disabled through:

System / Configuration / General / Web / Url Options / Add Store Code to Urls

**Note:**

I do not remember setting this option to Yes. I've seen some reports that this setting could be changing automatically (4 people reporting it):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/192613/

Comment: The code responsible for this is in function setPathInfo in the file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php. Section "if ($this->_canBeStoreCodeInUrl()) {"